# SCSS npm is not compiling CSS when I use -w "watch:sass"

Tags: npm, sass, compilation

SCSS npm is not compiling CSS when I use `-w "watch:sass"`

```
   "scripts": {
            "watch:sass": "node-sass sass/main.scss css/style.css -w",
            "devserver": "live-server --browser=firefox",
            "start": "npm-run-all --parallel devserver watch:sass",
```

Comment: What is it doing?

Comment: Explain what exactly happens.

Comment: it froze on the terminal and the update did not work. if I remove the -w than it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

it froze on the terminal and the update did not work. if I remove the -w than it works perfectly.

```
 {
 "name": "nikesh",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Landing page for natours",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "watch:sass": "node-sass sass/main.scss css/style.css -w",
    "devserver": "live-server",
    "start": "npm-run-all --parallel devserver watch:sass",

    "compile:sass": "node-sass sass/main.scss css/style.comp.css",
    "concat:css": "concat -o css/style.concat.css css/icon-font.css css/style.comp.css",
    "prefix:css": "postcss --use autoprefixer -b 'last 10 versions' css/style.concat.css -o css/style.prefix.css",
    "compress:css": "node-sass css/style.prefix.css css/style.css --output-style compressed",
    "build:css": "npm-run-all compile:sass concat:css prefix:css compress:css"
  },
  "author": "tandel",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^7.1.4",
    "concat": "^1.0.3",
    "node-sass": "^4.5.3",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.1",
    "postcss-cli": "^4.1.1"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing

```
"watch:sass": "node-sass sass/main.scss css/style.css -w",
```

try this one

```
"sass": "node-sass -w sass/main.scss -o css/style.css --recursive",
```

here,

1. **-w** : means we have to watch the sass/main.scss file
2. **-o** : means to need to save the output in the css/style.css file

Answer (score 0):

What fixed my issue is that I finally noticed it was compiling everything into the wrong file when I compiled sass in my terminal. I tweaked my package.json and all the changes I made in my files finally compiled correctly and I was able to see the live-changes.